# I can't Insert irow in DB2

Tags: sql, string, db2, sql-insert

```
insert into Persons values(1, "Perez", "Manuel", "Roma 231", "Bue")

Run time:
0.007 s
Status:
Failed
Error message
"Perez" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.26.14
```

The table was created this way:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);
```

Comment: Use single quotes for strings, not double quotes.

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes for literal strings:

```
insert into Persons values(1, 'Perez', 'Manuel', 'Roma 231', 'Bue');
                    -- here  -^-   -^--^-    -^--^-      -^--^- -^-
```

In standard SQL (and in DB2 as well), double quotes stand for quoted identifiers (such as table names or column names).

Comment: In addition, add the columns in the insert: `insert into Persons (PersonID,LastName,FirstName,Address,City) values (1, 'Perez', 'Manuel', 'Roma 231', 'Bue')` It will be beneficial for anyone looking at the code later on, beside will continue to work if the table for one reason or another changes the order of columns.

Answer (score -3):

insert into is written like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value, ...);
```

so it should be:

```
insert into Persons ( PersonID,LastName,FirstName,Address,City)
    values(1, "Perez", "Manuel", "Roma 231", "Bue")
```

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers. Use single quotes for string literals.